# Import conversion from GA4 to Google Ads triggers an error

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-api, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to import a conversion from GA4 to Google Ads but the error message is unclear: "An error occurred. Please try again later.".

I also checked the responses in browser console and found this "FIELD ERROR VALUE NOT WHITELISTED".

The conversion looks good and is tracked properly in GA4.

Any idea about how can I fix this issue?

Thanks!

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8CoZ.jpg)